Does a GitHub Actions composite action run all steps within the same shell and is it able to export environment variables to the invoking job?
Consider a GitHub Action composite action, like (snippet only):
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        client-id: ${{ inputs.clientId }}
        tenant-id: ${{ inputs.tenantId }}
        allow-no-subscriptions: true
    - name: Get Token
      id: get-token
      run: |
        token=$(az account get-access-token --scope=${{ inputs.ammaScope }} --query accessToken --output tsv)
        echo "::add-mask::$token"
        echo "token=$token" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}"
      shell: bash

I'm confused about the following:

Does each step run in a separate Bash shell (shell: bash)? Normally, all steps within a job runs in the same shell. If yes, is this the same shell, as the other steps in the invoking job?
Is it possible for composite actions to export environment variables (export MY_VAR=MY_VALUE), or can it only communicate with the other steps in the invoking job via outputs?
How can I get rid of warnings about: "pre execution is not supported for local action from './.github/actions/register-api'"?

I think the following references don't describe the above. Where can I lookup for technical details of composite actions?
References:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action


Composite actions are like job steps, they all run in the same runner instance (the one configured in the action calling the composite action) and if you don't specify different shell for each step, they will run on the same one as well.

Regarding the environments variables, you can export them outside the action, to the main job calling it, through outputs ($GITHUB_OUTPUTS) like in the link you shared, or through the GITHUB_ENV context as well.

Lastly, regarding the warning message, pre and post steps have not been supported in composite actions yet. This is a highly requested feature, you can track it in actions/runner#1478.

@GuiFalourd - Thank you. By "the action calling the composite action", you mean the job step with a uses: ./.github/actions/register-api referencing the composite action? Isn't it required to specify the shell: key for each composite step?

The reason I asked for exporting environment variables was that I wanted to define a composite action that sets environment variables for the calling job. But I couldn't find any docs regarding this, and I don't want to base production code on heuristic behaviour. How do you know these technical details, like shell: and $GITHUB_ENV? Would you provide me with links to relevant docs? :)


You are right, I meant the job referencing the composite action. 2. You can specify the shell for each step, but if you don't, it will use the runner default shell. 3. The shell documentation details can be found here, and the $GITHUB_ENV variable is documented here

